# MAMP and CGI Files

Tags: php, cgi, mamp

I am trying to help a friend redesign his e-commerce website running off of PHP (or at least I am assuming it's PHP). I got a copy of the website locally and am trying to run it in MAMP.

I copied the website over to the htdocs folder and can get to the index page fine. When I try to login I get the error :

```
 Not Found

 The requested URL /cgi-bin/commerce.cgi was not found on this server.
```

I know that the .cgi file is there. Is there something special I have to do with MAMP to be able to get it to run correctly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to activate cgi.
If you use MAMP Pro there is a special option in the Host settings - advanced tab for enabling ExecCGI.

If you are not using MAMP Pro you have to check in the apache https.conf file for:

```
MAMP_cgi_module_MAMPLoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

And

```
#
# ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
# ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
# documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
# run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
# client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
# directives as to Alias.
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/"
```